# Commiting from wrong branch and how to resolve conflicts in GIT

Tags: git, github, merge

I have three branches. 
- local working branch
- local master branch
- remote master branch

Normally I commit from local working branch to local master first and then push the code to the remote master.

By accident, I worked on code inside local master and committed from there.
After I realized I did it in the wrong branch, I repeated it in the local branch.

Now I get conflicts when I merge from local working branch to local master.

How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've got nothing of value in the local master any more, right?  Everything you care about is in the local working branch, so you could throw away what you did on the local master and not lose anything.

In which case, you could forcibly reset the local master branch, something like:

```
# check out your local master:
git checkout master
# force your local master to be identical to the remote master:
git reset --hard remote/master
```

But I may misunderstand your description.